# Slack cannot open files on external drive (in /mnt and /media)

Tags: 18.04, permissions, snap, slack

I have installed Slack (Desktop App) and I had trouble uploading and downloading files from/to certain directories for months.
More specifically, it seems that Slack don't have the permission to access directories in `/mnt` and `/media` (and various other directories outside of `/home`).

I don't upload files from USB sticks everyday, however I have a dual boot ubuntu+windows and my `~/Downloads` is a symlink to `/mnt/win10/.../Downloads`, and downloading files or sending files I downloaded previously is really fastidious.

I tried to change the umask of the mounted ntfs partition from `dmask=027,fmask=137` to `dmask=000,fmask=111` in `/etc/fstab`, to no avail.
Slack cannot see the content of `/mnt` itself anyway (despite that permissions are `rwxr-xr-x`).

This [github issue](https://github.com/flathub/com.slack.Slack/issues/46) seemed to be the most enlightening post I could find, however I installed Slack using snap, not flatpak (and I have no problem sending files in `~/` or even `/lib`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I too had faced the same issue. This is because the app did not have permission to read/write files on removable storage devices. To resolve this:

1. Go to ubuntu setting.
2. Go to Application.
3. Search for Slack. Click on Slack. It will list all permission and access options for Slack.
4. Enable read/write files on removable storage devices option.

Once enabled, you will be able to browse removable storage and upload/download files from the removable storage.

Comment: Thanks! I found the options in snap (Ubuntu Software). Worked like a charm!